# How to Get "input="file"" Effect With jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input-type-file

I want to open windows where user may choose file from his/her computer. Only problem, without this:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use a flash plugin, like (for example) gmail does.

Comment: why do you want achieve it without using type=file...? Just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your needs/restrictions are, but you could try using the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) plugin. It's nice and super-simple to use.